# Can SoupStrainer have two arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Well this started out as a question but halfway through I figured it out. I can't find a question like this on stackoverflow or Google, so I'll post it anyway to help anyone who stumbles across it.

I wanted to use SoupStrainer from BeautifulSoup to parse two tags instead of one in an html document.

I knew I could do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('p'))
```

This would get the `<p>` tags. I also wanted to get the `<h3>` tags. So I tried this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('h3', 'p'))
```

But this wouldn't work because SoupStrainer only takes one argument.

Answer is below.

Comment: If you are going to self-answer, put the answer part in a *separate answer post*.

Answer (score 4):

To make SoupStrainer parse *multiple tags*, you need to put them in a *list*. Like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(['h3', 'p']))
```

This parses **both** the `<h3>` and `<p>` tags in `content.text`, even if they are siblings (i.e. one tag is not inside of the other).

You can do this with *more than two tags* also, as long as you pass them to SoupStrainer as *one list*.

One tag:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('p'))
```

Multiple tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(['h1', 'h3', 'p', 'h4']))
```

Comment: I know it has been a long time but is it also possible to parse multiple tags but only those with a specific attribute. I tried putting like  soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer([('h1', {class="foo"}), 'h3', 'p', 'h4'])) but this did not work

Answer (score 1):

There is much more power in `regex`. Use the `re` module.

> This would get the `<p>` tags. I also wanted to get the `<h3>` tags.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(re.compile(r"p|h3")))
```

@Martijn
For attributes, you can use the `attrs`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(re.compile(r"p|h3")), class_="foo")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(re.compile(r"p|h3")), attrs={"class": "foo"})
```

But you obviously cannot apply a `class` for each HTML `tag`. You can work around it by using `css` selectors.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(["h1", "h2", "h3", "p"])).select("h1.foo, h2, h3, p")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the constructor of `SoupStrainer` is defined in bs4:

```
class SoupStrainer(object):
    """Encapsulates a number of ways of matching a markup element (tag or
    text)."""

    def __init__(self, name=None, attrs={}, text=None, **kwargs):

...
```

So, adding to @JohnStrood's answer, you can use the `attrs` argument (a dictionary) to restrict matches by one or more attributes:

```
attrs_dict = { "class": "foo", "other_attr": ["value1", "value2"] }
strainer = SoupStrainer([h3, p], attrs=attrs_dict)
```